# Hide (Encrypted) windows installation under Linux

Tags: linux, windows, encryption, truecrypt

I've got a PC running Linux (Ubuntu, in case it makes any difference).
I want to install windows (Seven) to a hidden-encrypted partition on that drive.

So on boot-up I have a selection screen:

1. If I choose "Linux" it boot up Linux.
2. If I choose "Windows" it ask for a password to mount the encrypted volume.

While [TrueCrypt](http://truecrypt.sourceforge.net/) seems exactly what I was looking for,
Apparently it can only do the opposite ([hide Linux under Windows](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/hidden-operating-system)).

Comment: The site you're linking to doesn't put any restriction on the OS to be hidden - you may however have to either have the "windows" option actually start the original "mount hidden volume" "fake windows" or use a linux encryption tool like dm-crypt

Comment: @TobiasKienzler  Thanks for your comment! When trying to use the "hidden operating system" (with TrueCrypt) from a Linux system, the application says that it is not possible (some discussions on the internet says the same)

Comment: You're welcome (and also welcome to superuser.com!). If that's all you needed to implement this, don't hesitate to post an answer here afterwards

Comment: @TobiasKienzler  My Linux knowledge is pretty lame ... So any tutorial link or a bit more detailed explanation on how to use "dm-crypt" to achieve my goal would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know for sure if dm-crypt can be used together with windows, so you should probably stick to truecrypt - use a spoof windows bootloader and add a Linux entry à la [these instructions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Windows_and_Arch_Dual_Boot#Using_Windows_7.2F8_boot_loader)

Answer (score 1):

qemu works quite well under linux. I would just run 7 as a qemu installation.
Use synaptic to download "aqemu" and dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

**WARNING Using TrueCrypt is not anymore secure as it may** [**contain unfixed security issues**](http://truecrypt.sourceforge.net/)
From May 2014 developers discontinued Truecrypt and suggest to migrate from TrueCrypt to [BitLocker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitLocker)

If your computer is fast enough and/or the **main aim is the security** a solution can be to install an **encrypted virtual machine** ([vmware](http://www.vmware.com/) or [virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) [Qemu](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page)...or any of the [**Hypervisor**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor))  that presents some advantages as you can read in [Is dual-booting an OS more or less secure than running a virtual machine?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/16615/is-dual-booting-an-os-more-or-less-secure-than-running-a-virtual-machine?rq=1)

Nowadays it exists a wide range of programs that allows to create an encrypted partition.
It's possible to give a look to the [list in wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_disk_encryption_software) choosing among the operative system on which they reside, their licence (Proprietary, GPL, BSD, Open Source...) and the features they provide

> **Hidden containers**: Whether hidden containers (an encrypted container (A) within another encrypted container (B) so the existence of container A can not be established) can be created for deniable encryption. Note that some modes of operation like CBC with a plain IV can be more prone to watermarking attacks than others.
>   **Pre-boot authentication**: Whether authentication can be required before booting the computer, thus allowing one to encrypt the boot disk.
>   **Single sign-on**: Whether credentials provided during pre-boot authentication will automatically log the user into the host operating system, thus preventing password fatigue and reducing the need to remember multiple passwords.
>   **Custom authentication:** Whether custom authentication mechanisms can be implemented with third-party applications.
>   **Multiple keys**: Whether an encrypted volume can have more than one active key.
>   **Passphrase strengthening**: Whether key strengthening is used with plain text passwords to frustrate dictionary attacks, usually using PBKDF2.
>   **Hardware acceleration**: Whether dedicated cryptographic accelerator expansion cards can be taken advantage of.
>   **Trusted Platform Module**: Whether the implementation can use a TPM cryptoprocessor.
>   **Filesystems**: what filesystems are supported.
>   **Two-factor authentication**: Whether optional security tokens (hardware security modules, such as Aladdin eToken and smart cards) are supported (for example using PKCS#11)